# Why Function.prototype cannot be modified ?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

in the [Function.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype) page it's written this :

> Function objects inherit from Function.prototype.  Function.prototype
>   cannot be modified.

Or in javascript there are no classes but the Inheritance and the prototype chaining in which constructors are actually functions :

```
function AclassName(){
    return 2;
}

// AclassName ---> Function.prototype ---> Object.prototype ---> null
```

and i think it's always possible to extend the class prototype's like :

```
AclassName.prototype.color = "somevlue";
```

So what does it mean that i can't be modified ?

Comment: It means you are _in no way_ allowed to mess with a feature so essential as `function`. Overwriting methods on other objects causes adverse effects, but a `function` object is _essential_ for any other methods and functions to work as expected, so you are not allowed to modify it _at all_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in JS has a prototype (even if it's null). So, the prototype of an actual `function` is `Function.prototype`.

When you assign or modify `AclassName.prototype` in your example, you're setting the prototype for **instances** of `AclassName`. Note that the prototype of an object `x` is **not the same as** `x.prototype`. That `.prototype` is used for setting the prototype that will be used for *instances* of x, if x is used as a constructor.

To put it another way:

Your function AClassName,  declared with `function AClassName () {}`, is an object of class **Function**, so it inherits from `Function.prototype`.

If you instantiate that class:

```
var myInstance = new AClassName();
```

Then `myInstance` is an object of class **AClassName**, so it inherits from `AClassName.prototype`.

So to answer the root of your question: `Function.prototype` cannot be modified, because it's a core part of the language and being able to change it might introduce performance or security issues. However, you are totally at liberty to modify the prototypes of your own classes.

Comment: Do you have an idea why we can do: 
`Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};`
If `Function.prototype` cannot be modified ?

Answer (score 0):

I have to point it out that:the prototype of Function is `Function.prototype`, but a specific function like foo, it's prototype is not `Function.prototype`.

`Function.prototype` is a callable object, it is a "function" `(typeof Function.prototype).foo.prototype` is an "object". When you Function constructor construct a function like foo, it runs a code: `this.prototype={constructor:this}` (This is from "The JavaScript: good parts", Douglas Crockford); i.e `foo.prototype={constructor:foo}`.