# why MDN says that the "Function.prototype cannot be modified"?

Tags: javascript

In [Function.prototype page in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype) says that the `Function.prototype` cannot be modified". But when I tried the following code in the console, it proved me that you can modify the existing properties of the Function.prototype, as well as we can add new properties to it.

```js
Function.prototype.call = function(context) {
  console.log("call() fn has been modified");
};

var f = function() {
  //do something..
};

f.call(this);
```

and it shows the following as the result in the console.

```
call() fn has been modified
```

If the `Function.prototype` cannot be modified, why I am seeing such a behavior?

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897762/why-function-prototype-cannot-be-modified) question refers to the same problem. But there what has been modified is the 'AclassName.prototype'. not the Function.prototype.

Comment: I think MDN's wording here is slightly miss-leading,. `Function.prototype cannot be modified`, maybe should have said `Function.prototype cannot be replaced`  IOW: The object that represents the `prototype` can be modified, but the actual object itself that's assigned to `Function` cannot be changed.   Or as much simpler example,  `Function.prototype = null`,  does nothing..

Comment: @Keith is correct.
`Function.prototype = { call: function() {return "modified"} }` - this does not do anything even though it does not give an error. 

But, `Function.prototype.call = function() { return "modified" }`
will be changed. @Keith any comment on that?

Answer (score 4):

`Function.prototype` is not `Function.prototype.call`, normally you can do `SomeConstructor.prototype = { ... }`, but you cannot do `Function.prototype = { ... }`.

Comment: But according to the definition of 'prototype modifying', you shouldn't be able to modify and properties in the Function.prototype isn't it?